# How To Duck Audio in Logic Pro X

Tags: macos, garageband, logic

In garageband ducking audio was a one-click operation.  However I cannot find how to preform the same action in Logic Pro X.

Comment: http://www.logicprohelp.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=99410 might be of some help?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using sidechain compression in Logic. 
Create a new track and insert a sound (eg Kick drum) on every part you want the sound to duck, then set the output to no output. 
Go to the track you want to duck and add a compressor and then set the side chain input to the track you created in the step above. 
Tweak the threshold, attack and release settings to get your desired effect.